# Error during Installing nltk 2.0.4 on python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am new to python and trying to install NLTK 2.0.4 but following exception is thrown:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\AHMADR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j3n9bb9v\nltk\

Any suggestion to get rid of this error or any other way to install this version on python 3.6. 
My OS is Windows and I am using  this command to install

```
pip install -Iv nltk==2.0.4
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the whole stack trace. The bit you posted tells us *what* went wrong, but not *where*.

Comment: Please see https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9 or  or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68aHmFcO-W4